# Control DiscolsurePanel collapsing by another button instead of header text

Tags: java, javascript, gwt

I went through GWT Showcase and I found disclosure panel.
I want to control disclosure panel collapsing and expanding by clicking on one button.
In certain situations button can be disabled, In that case I want to enable/disable button.

Please refer this for more details:

[image]

Please suggest, How to do this?

Comment: _"In certain situations button can be disabled, In that case I want to enable/disable button."_ If the button is disabled you want to use the button? That doesn't really make sense.

Comment: Thanks Baz. Sorry for my bad English. Actually when button is disabled then I want to disable disclosure panel also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`setOpen`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/DisclosurePanel.html#setOpen%28boolean%29), but note that you cannot disable the `DisclosurePanel` and prevent it from opening when clicking its header.

You might want to build a custom widget instead.

Comment: Thanks Thomas. Should I create that custom widget by extending DisclosurePanel or any other way is suitable? Please suggest.